# Xcode 4 Documentation References?

Tags: xcode, documentation, reference, xcode4

I'm using now Xcode 4 and cannot access the documentation. I typed in `UITableView` in the search-field, but nothing is there.

What's wrong with Xcode? Do I have to download something ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is about why XCode is not working normally. Feel free to modify my edit if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Xcode's Preferences -> Documentation and download the set you need.